# YouTube Data API v3 quota exceeded on the first upload

Tags: java, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to develop a desktop application in Java for uploading videos. I create a new Google account, create project on developer console and create credentials (ClientID and ClientSecret). After creating all of these, i do authorization (as in java examples), the application opens browser window for me to allow the application to manage the channel, and everything works fine. 
But when i try to upload a video (short video, tried it on other channels before and it uploaded every time), i immediately get quota exceeded response. And in the developer console i can see that quota is actually exceeded (9644 queries already). I must add that this is happening only for the newly registered accounts - the same video uploads without issues using the same app.
Why is this happening? Is there any way I can "register" new account and immediately do upload? If not, how can I do this properly? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with the python code that i used (i modified code based on https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/uploading_a_video). I solved it using the following workflow:

- create a (new) google account if you dont have one yet
- go to youtube, sign up with the google account and create a channel
- go to
  https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?pli=1
- create a project, pick a name
- click on OAuth consent screen, pick external, pick application name
- go back to Credentials, create Credentials using OAuthClient ID, pick Web application
- pick a name, put into redirect urls: http://localhost:8080/ and https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground and save
- go to Dashboard, search YouTube Data API v3 and enable
- then go to https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/
- click on the rack wheel on the right, click use your own credentials, copy and past clientID and secret client from https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials and close
- search for Youtube Data API v3 on the left, and select https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload and https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube
- click authorize APIs, log into your account, agree to all questions asked
- Click Exchange authorization code for token
- the Request on the right should not give you any errors
- go back to https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials, when you click on the edit button next to your credentials, you should be able to download your JSON files. put them into the script folder under client_secrets.json
- make sure to delete the file python_upload_video.py-oauth2.json from previous trys
- when running the code with for example

  ```
    python upload_video.py --file="input.mp4" --privacyStatus="unlisted"
  ```

the browser should open and ask you to log into your account

what i noticed is that:

- if you get three errors in three hours it seems to exceed the quota and you cannot continue
- the upload works for about 5 videos a day. If you need to upload more and cannot wait the only way is to create a new account and repeat the steps above (as far as I know)

Answer (score 0):

It may be worth investigating further: I guess that your issue has to do with the API issues seen since about three days now. See the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/55220182/8327971; also Google's known and acknowledged issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/128673552.