# YouTubes API for getting the latest videos from a channel

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to get the latest, up to date videos from a channel on youtube. Not sure why, but         `order: 'date',` ,         `publishedAfter: '2019-03-13T19:14:31.000Z',` and `publishedBefore: '2019-02-13T19:14:31.000Z',` don't seem to have an effect.

The full code of what I'm using is here below:

```
baseURL: 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3',
params: {
    part: 'snippet',
    publishedAfter: '2019-03-13T19:14:31.000Z',
    publishedBefore: '2019-02-13T19:14:31.000Z',
    order: 'date',
    maxResults: 10,
    key: KEY,
    channelId: 'UCzQUP1qoWDoEbmsQxvdjxgQ'
}
```

Is youtube messing around with the API? Is there a special way we are meant to be doing this? Maybe my ordering is wrong? I'm quite confused

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Youtube Data API v3: Sort by date not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55195054/youtube-data-api-v3-sort-by-date-not-working)

Answer (score 1):

This is a temporary issue, as per the Google forums : https://support.google.com/youtube/thread/2494861?msgid=2520468

> YouTube is aware the search/sorting functions aren't working as expected – this is temporary and part of our efforts to better respond, review and remove graphic, violative content from YouTube.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is related to the following ones:

- [Order doesn't work when using youtube API v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55197345/order-doesnt-work-when-using-youtube-api-v3);
- [publishedAfter parameter appears to be broken now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55205342/publishedafter-parameter-appears-to-be-broken-now);
- [Youtube Data API v3: Sort by date not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55195054/youtube-data-api-v3-sort-by-date-not-working).

See also Google's issue #128673552, https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/128673552.

A workaround for this issue: use PlaylistItems endpoint instead, queried for a channel's uploads list. However your should be aware of the difference between a video's *published time* and *upload time* (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#snippet.publishedAt).