# Youtube Data API is returning invalid data

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm not really sure how to ask this, but I have a php script that pulls data from the youtube-v3-api for my youtube channel, mainly a list of videos that I have published. It's been working great up until earlier today when I went to run it again because I added a new video. Here's the output for the first object in the items array

```
items:[  
   {  
      kind:"youtube#searchResult",
      etag:""      XpPGQXPnxQJhLgs6enD_n8JR4Qk/tluoWYe5GE9lVFAkcMtcec2Ycug"",
      id:{  
         kind:"youtube#channel",
         channelId:"UCD8d3FGC907iS1qiMF0ccxA"
      },
      snippet:{  
         publishedAt:"2006-04-30T19:39:08.000Z",
         channelId:"UCD8d3FGC907iS1qiMF0ccxA",
         title:"Travis Ballard",
         description:"",
         thumbnails:{  
            default:{  
               url:"https://yt3.ggpht.com/-L5MV7tUNjlk/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/dXNuqxAYprw/s88-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg"
            },
            medium:{  
               url:"https://yt3.ggpht.com/-L5MV7tUNjlk/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/dXNuqxAYprw/s240-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg"
            },
            high:{  
               url:"https://yt3.ggpht.com/-L5MV7tUNjlk/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/dXNuqxAYprw/s800-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg"
            }
         },
         channelTitle:"Travis Ballard",
         liveBroadcastContent:"none"
      }
   }
]
```

This does not represent a video on my channel? also, it's not in order at all. It should be ordered by date as i'm asking it to in my php script:

```
    <?php

  const APIKEY = 'MyAPIKeyHere';
  const CHANNELID = 'UCD8d3FGC907iS1qiMF0ccxA';
  const VIDEO_COUNT = 50;

  class FetchYoutubeVideos {

    private $api_key = null;
    private $channel_id = null;
    private $count = null;

    public function __construct($api_key, $channel_id, $count = 10) {
      $this->api_key = $api_key;
      $this->channel_id = $channel_id;
      $this->count = $count;

      $this->writeToFile(
        'videos.json',
        $this->fetch($this->getApiUrl())
      );
      printf( 'fetched videos from: %s', $this->getApiUrl());
    }

    public function getApiUrl($options = array()) {
      $endpoint = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search';
      $default_options = array(
        'key' => $this->api_key,
        'channelId' => $this->channel_id,
        'part' => 'snippet,id',
        'order' => 'date',
        'maxResults' => $this->count
      );

      $options = array_merge($options, $default_options);
      return sprintf('%s/?%s', $endpoint, http_build_query($options));
    }

    public function fetch($url) {
      $ch = curl_init($url);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

      $result = curl_exec($ch);
      return $result;
    }

    public function writeToFile($filename, $data) {;
      $fh = fopen($filename, 'w+');
      fwrite($fh, $data, strlen($data));
      fclose($fh);
    }
  }

  $fetchVideos = new FetchYoutubeVideos(APIKEY, CHANNELID, VIDEO_COUNT);
```

The newest video should be 'Tragic - Rock-a-Hoola Revisited' and then 'Rocket Timelapse - Anycubic i3 Mega'. You can reference my yt channel to see what it should be returning: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCD8d3FGC907iS1qiMF0ccxA?view_as=subscriber

Any insights into why it changed? Or why it's not returning the data that it should be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You experienced an API issue which is known for a few days now. Follow-up https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/128673552, or the answers already given on this site (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/55246970/8327971).

Either of the two links we'll lead you to find a workaround for the issue at hand.

Note that, until now, Google has refrained itself from providing an ETA for when it'll enable back the API's features it disabled. I suppose that it may well take a few more days (perhaps weeks?) until we'll see those disabled features working again.