# YouTube Data API search endpoint not working with order parameter

Tags: python, youtube-data-api

It seems that `order='date'` parameter of YouTube Data API (v3) search endpoint does not work as expected since last week. I can't get the videos sorted in reverse chronological order. I've just tested it in [APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.search.list?part=snippet&channelId=UCCCPCZNChQdGa9EkATeye4g&maxResults=25&order=date), the returned results are not either sorted by date. Below is my code in Python:

```
import requests

requests.get('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search',
             params={
                 'key': YOUTUBE_API_KEY,
                 'part': 'snippet',
                 'type': 'video',
                 'order': 'date',
                 'channelId': 'UCCCPCZNChQdGa9EkATeye4g',
             })
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a known and acknowledged issue of the API (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/55246970/8327971).

Follow also the longish thead at Google: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/128673552. There is to be found some useful workarounds.

Until now, Google refrained itself from providing an ETA for when it'll reinstate the API features it disabled.